# How do I transfer data along with a redirect?

Tags: php, windows-7, iis-7, joomla1.5

This code, obviously, redirects from where it is (in a 404 handler) to a custom 404 handler.

```
header('Location: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4' );
```

Aside from adding extra items to the invocation, e.g.

```
header('Location: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&param=foo' );
```

is there any other way of transferring data? For instance, is there a mechanism for sending form data along with the transfer of location?

*Context: Windows7, IIS7, PHP 5, Joomla! 1.5*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If you are redirecting to a different location within the same domain and all you really need is to redirect the data, consider using a redirect configured with the web server. I have done it with Apache. With [IIS7 it shouldn't be too difficult](http://www.surfingsuccess.com/asp/iis-url-rewrite.html#.UbJUsfleYZ4).

If you need to do something additional (capture or manipulate the data before passing it on) then you might consider using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), saving posted data to the session rather than re-posting the post data to the new location.

If you need to post data received to a new location (and especially if the domain is outside your control) and render the result (not caring to actually redirect in the browser), then [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) might be useful.

Here is some example code:

```
if(!empty($_GET['url'])) $url = $_GET['url'];
else $url = 'localhost/default.php';

$post = array
(
  'example_post_var_1' => 'foo',
  'example_post_var_2' => 'bar'
);

$options = array
(
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post)
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
if(!$result = curl_exec($ch))
{
  trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
}

echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
exit();
```

Comment: So let me get this straight. You seem to be saying that I can use cURL to redirect to another page, yes? Do you want to post a link to an example?

Comment: Figured it out and woo hoo, you ripper!!

Answer (score 2):

[Session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) can preserve data across requests.